# MySQL Insert New Row, Update on Duplicate Keys, Trigger if one key changes

Tags: mysql

I've two tables that I'm working with, defined as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE dns_addresses_resolved (
    id INT(13) NOT NULL REFERENCES dns_addresses(id),
    malware_id INT(13) REFERENCES malware_families(id),
    type VARCHAR(10),
    ttl int(10),
    address VARCHAR(50),
    first_resolved DATETIME,
    last_resolved DATETIME,
        PRIMARY KEY (id, address)

)

CREATE TABLE dns_addresses_resolved_archive (
    id INT(13) NOT NULL REFERENCES dns_addresses(id),
    malware_id INT(13) REFERENCES malware_families(id),
    type VARCHAR(10),
    ttl int(10),
    address VARCHAR(50),
    first_resolved DATETIME,    /* When was this IP first seen */
    archived_date DATETIME,     /* The date that the IP changes, and the 'old' IP is archived */
        PRIMARY KEY (id, address)

)
```

> What I'm trying to do is:
>
> 1. INSERT row if dns_addresses_resolved.id AND dns_addresses_resolved.resolved_address don't exist
> 2. ON DUPLICATE KEY {in dns_addresses_resolved} UPDATE last_resolved = NOW()
> 3. Here's the part I get stuck on. When dns_addresses_resolved.resolved_address changes, move the data
>      currently in that row to `dns_addresses_resolved_archive`. I was
>      looking at using a trigger to do this last part, but where I get stuck
>      is when just resolved_address changes.
>
> I'm thinking that I came up with two of the three parts, as seen below
>   and I was just wondering of anyone could shed some light on this for
>   me! I know that I could use logic within code to do this, but I'm
>   making life hard on myself because .. well, learning is fun!
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO dns_addresses_resolved (id, type, ttl, resolved_address, first_resolved, last_resolved)       VALUES ( ?, ?, ?,
> ```
>
> ?, NOW(), NOW() )         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_resolved = NOW()
>
> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER dns_resolved_archive   BEFORE UPDATE ON dns_addresses_resolved.resolved_address    FOR EACH ROW    BEGIN       INSERT
> ```
>
> INTO dns_addresses_resolved_archive       VALUES ($oldTable.id,
>   $oldTable.malware_id, $oldTable.type, $oldTable.ttl,
>   $oldTable.resolved_address, $oldTable.first_resolved, NOW());     END
>
> I'm also more than open to suggestions if anyone has a more logical
>   way of doing what I'm trying to do. I'd love your input!

EDIT: I figured out a trigger, though updates to 'address' fail, and cause a mysql error and I don't know why. The error is

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'dns_addresses_resolved.id' in 'field list'

Which seems completely straight forward at first. When I run the following update *with* the trigger, I get the error. When I run that same query *without* the trigger, the update works fine.

```
update dns_addresses_resolved set address = 'google.com' where id = 1;
```

Below is my trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER archive_old_dns_resolution
BEFORE UPDATE ON dns_addresses_resolved
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.address <> OLD.address THEN
        INSERT INTO dns_addresses_resolved_archive
        VALUES ($oldTable.id, $oldTable.malware_id, $oldTable.type, $oldTable.ttl, $oldTable.address, $oldTable.first_resolved, NOW());
    END IF;
END
```

So given that a trigger seems like the most logical solution to what I'm trying to do, why does this trigger cause a SQL error ON UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get a duplicate in the case of a change to the `resolved_address`, as the compound primary key will not exist for that `id`/`resolved_address` combination.  In this case a straight insert will happen. I also don't think an UPDATE trigger would work for you as, even if you address a separate index for `id` only such that an update would be triggered, you would have no way of knowing whether the update was triggered for the case where only the timestamp should be update or for when a new `resolved_address` was provided.

I am guessing that you are trying to get this done with a single query against the server, but I don't know if you have a clean solution to that since in essence you have two unique indexes (one on `id` and one on `id`,`resolved_address`) that you want to provide different behavior for should an entry already exist when trying to do an insert.

My guess is that you will either need to create a stored procedure (if you want a single database call), or you will need to use multiple queries to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. That was more or less the conclusion that I'd come to. I was just hoping someone would have a magic answer for me :)

Comment: I found a solution, but updates now fail when the trigger fires. OP has been updated to include my trigger.